# How to build a full screen html 5 web app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, fullscreen

Are there any currently accepted methods for building full screen web applications in HTML 5 using just JavaScript and CSS?

If so, what are the pros and cons of each? What cross-browser quirks are there?

Comment: When you say full screen you just want a browser to cover the whole screen, right? That's simple, in most browsers you just click F11. Doesn't matter what css/js/html you have. Dunno if you can do it from code though.

Comment: You can't force the browser to go fullscreen through javascript without the user doing it themself.

Comment: i was thinking similar to how it works with flash or HTML 5 video where you have a fullscreen icon that makes it go into full screen mfode. I think this is better than f11 since it doesn't modify the user's browser environment other than the app itself. It would also allow the user to use escape to exit as has become a bit of a convention. Also don't want to have to rely on the way the browser handles full screen. For example, some browsers may implement full screen differently, or not at all without any way to feature detect.

Comment: or if there were a browser API for full screen I didn't know about. Ultimately I want to write programs that allow and encourage users to interact in fullscreen mode in the most usable way.

Comment: The full screen mode of the HTML5 media element interface is provided by the browser specifically for media where a full screen mode makes sense for the user (e.g. video). However, browsers provide user controls so that **users** are in control over whether the element is full screen or not. It is not intended for a kiosk mode, nor is it controlable by script (althoughs script can usually control the size of the window and elements within it to approximate a full-screen mode). You can run IE in [kiosk mode](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154780) from the command prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is bleeding edge, but the latest chrome builds have a Fullscreen API. See this slide deck for details:

http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/html5-whats-new/template/index.html#42

Also, it looks like these dudes figured out a way to do it without resorting to unsupported features:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/gopherwoord-studios-resizing-html5-games.html

Comment: both links broken.

Answer (score 2):

There is [a proposal](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko%3aFullScreenAPI) which is based on [discussions on the WHATWG mailing list](http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/2010-December/029395.html).  This was originally triggered by [this WebKit API](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/50893), but as far as I'm aware that only works on iOS and there are no other implementations at present.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, Full Screen mode can only be induced by the user directly telling the browser to go into that mode.

It's like back in the slave days. You're the slave, the user is the master, and pixels are your food. They may not give you much, but they give you some, and you have to savor every last bit.

Answer (score 0):

This used to be possible back in the day - IE 4 did "Chromeless Windows" - but is no longer possible in pure HTML for security reasons.

If you can have the user install local software, something like [Mozilla Prism](http://prism.mozillalabs.com/) might work - I've never tried it myself though.

Comment: i understand the security implications, but it is available for HTML 5 video already and adobe seems to have done it right with flash. After all you dont seem to have flash apps that take over your screen.

Comment: @Adam all true, but as far as I know, it simply isn't possible in pure HTML. Re Flash - you have to trigger full screen mode manually, and you get a seconds-long "press Esc to leave" message, so yes, they have their precautions. I would like to see it come back for web sites, too, as an option.

Comment: hah, I should do a popup that says 'ie 4 required to use this app'

Comment: Prism is a dead project. Fluid is a good Mac alternative though, and Chrome on Windows has a "Create Application Shortcut" option.